# why I am getting segmentation fault when i am printing generic tree?

Tags: generics, tree, segmentation-fault

This is the code base.
I am not able to find out what is the error (run time) occuring in this code.
this display function displays the generic tree and in the main function the generic tree is being implemented.

tree node

```
   struct node
  {
int data;
vector<node*> children;
  node(int data){
    this->data = data;
  }
};
```

This is the display function.

```
 void display(node* n)
 {

string str = n->data+"->";
for(node* child:n->children)
{
    str+=child->data+",";
}
str+=".";
cout<<str<<endl;
for(node* child:n->children)
{
    display(child);
}
 }
```

this is the main

```
 int main()
{
   int arr[] = {10,20,50,-1,60,-1,-1,30,70,-1,80,110,-1,120,-1,-1,90,-1,-1,40,100,-1,-1,-1};
  node *root;
  stack<node*> st;
  for(int i=0 ; i<24 ;i++)
 {
    if(arr[i]==-1)
    {
        st.pop();
    }
    else{
        node *t = new node(arr[i]);
        if(st.size()>0)
        {
            st.top()->children.push_back(t);
        }
        else{
            root = t;
        }
            st.push(t);
            delete(t);
    }
}
display(root);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. At which line of code occurs the error? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors:

- The reason for the segmentation fault is that you `delete(t);` while the node is still referenced in the tree and the stack and needed later, which leads to use of corrupted memory. You'd have to delete the nodes only when the tree is deallocated eventually.
- You forgot to convert the `->data` to `string` in the display function.

  ```
  string str = to_string(n->data)+"->";
  …
      str += to_string(child->data)+",";
  ```